# Does extend imply a requires statement for this class?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Do I need to require a class if I extend from it or does the classmanger handle that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classmanager will take care of this. You will not need to require this class.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer